# Is a pointer to a null pointer defined in ANSI C?

Tags: c, pointers, null

Is this code (simplified from a real project) correct? Will the message always print?

```
char *cp = NULL;
char **cpp = &cp;
if(*cpp == NULL) {
    printf("I believe this will this always print. Does it?\n");
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will always print.

You can safely assume that your base [stack pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_pointer#Structure) never points to 0x0, so &cp will always not equal NULL.

In fact the compiler will eliminate the check at compile time, because it knows `&cp != NULL`.

See for yourself:

Compiled with `-O1`:

```
$ objdump -dC a.out 
a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64
  ...
00000000004004f4 <main>:
  4004f4:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  4004f8:       bf 00 06 40 00          mov    $0x400600,%edi
  4004fd:       e8 ee fe ff ff          callq  4003f0 <puts@plt>
  400502:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400507:       48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  40050b:       c3                      retq
```

(With `-O0` there will be a test, though:)

```
00000000004004f4 <main>:
  4004f4:       55                      push   %rbp
  4004f5:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4004f8:       48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  4004fc:       48 c7 45 f0 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x10(%rbp)
  400503:       00 
  400504:       48 8d 45 f0             lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
  400508:       48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
  40050c:       48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  400510:       48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
  400513:       48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
  400516:       75 0a                   jne    400522 <main+0x2e>
  400518:       bf 20 06 40 00          mov    $0x400620,%edi
  40051d:       e8 ce fe ff ff          callq  4003f0 <puts@plt>
  400522:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400527:       c9                      leaveq 
  400528:       c3                      retq
```

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown. Your `char **` pointer is pointing to a valid variable, thus it's always proper to dereference it.

P.S. Yes, it will always print.

Comment: @Heath Hunnicutt - Is there something wrong with the answer? I was reading between the lines of the question and guessing there was some confusion about how pointers to pointers actually work.

Comment: @Heath: I can't speak for Mark, of course ... but a) of course we want the points (how do you think we got to 40k or 20K or 6K); b) not really, points are overrated; c) I don't care for points: my answer wasn't suitable for a comment; d) if SO shuts down, I'll sell my points to the highest bidder

Comment: @pmg, thanks for the elaboration. Points aren't the end-all, but they're a good surrogate for measuring how helpful you've been. That's my primary motivation. As time goes on I find myself using comments as much or more than answers, even though comments don't affect your point scores.

Comment: P.S. I'll just say that some days it's hard to find a question you can answer! Not every song has to be a hit.

Comment: indeed; I also find myself doing more and more comments nowadays. I think @Heath was wondering why the community wiki check for answers is not used more :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course that always prints, why would it not?

The pointer you are dereferencing in your `if()` statement is `cpp`.  You only dereference one level, by using one `*` asterisk.  `cpp` may point to a `NULL` pointer, but `cpp` is not itself `NULL`.

On the other hand writing `char k = **cpp` should result in a crash of some sort.

Comment: Undefined Behavior "should" not necessarily do anything.  It might crash, it might "work", it might spew acid.

Comment: Blah, blah, undefined behavior.  Seriously irrelevant IRL.  Often used as a pretense for representing C as less predictable than it really is.  Nothing will be spewing acid, as an example.  I wager the OP is not coding on DOS, either.

Comment: @Heath: It's most definitely not irrelevant (well, acid probably is, but not the "might crash, might work").

Comment: UB is very relevant IRL here. If the compiler can determine statically that `**cpp` will always be a null pointer dereference, it can optimize out any code after it and any prior code paths that necessarily lead up to the dereference, on the assumption that they cannot happen.

Comment: "Most implementations usually cause segfaults when a NULL pointer is dereferenced." - true.  But many novice programmers wrongly generalize things like that to "the program will crash if I did something wrong".  The distinction is relevant.  (Also, optimizations might make a NULL dereference seem to work.)

Comment: @Oli: You're welcome to your opinion, but I disagree.  Yes, it might work on the Phillips LPC2106.  I seriously doubt OP or future reader needs to worry about that.  Pedantic UB blah blah blah typical of SO.  @R: How does that make it relevant?

Comment: I think it's just SO fashion to pretend you're "good" at C that people cite "UB" and "throw your hands up in the air" as soon as possible.  It's a joke and it's lame.

Comment: @Heath: Not everyone's writing code for an x86 with optimizations disabled!  Many embedded controllers/DSPs (for example) have no hardware trap for acessing 0x0000.

Comment: @Oli: These remarks about optimization are a sign of stupidity.  I challenge you to come up with one example of any C optimizer recognizing a NULL pointer dereference and then removing it.  As a point to be made in an argument, that's just a lie.

Comment: @Oli: I am well aware of that and mentioned, e.g., the  Phillips LPC2106.  Programmers on embedded platforms already understand what's going on.  Programmers who ask questions about NULL are not embedded systems programmers, they are learners.  In the year 2011, these people are using an OS where the dereference will crash.  This comment thread is a stupid argument where a bunch of wanna-bes would like to be "more right" by falling back on confusing details that are irrelevant in 99.99% of cases and surely irrelevant to OP.

Comment: @Heath: I'm not referring specifically to @R's example.  You appear to be making the general claim that UB != unpredictable (or rather, that any implication that is unpredictable is irrelevant), and that is simply wrong.

Comment: And by the way, the purpose of my first comment was not "ha ha you're wrong".  It was "this answer could be better if you replaced 'should' with 'will probably'".

Comment: @aschepler - Maybe if you replaced 'should' with 'in almost all environments you are likely to ever use, will crash'?  Consider the audience and keep it simple, but it's a community wiki because, really, getting points for answering such a question seems cheap.

Comment: @Heath: Why would I replace anything?  It's not my answer.